# Unable to catch primary key exception in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, exception, java.util.logging

I am inserting some values in a table and creating a new table in servlets.
I have wrote a code to catch SQLException and redirect to a jsp page with error msg.
While inserting new values in a table using servlet if a primary key constraint is getting violated my servlet is not catching the exception and i am getting a blank page.

My servlet code:-

```
package Servlets;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;


/**
 *
 * @author TALPESH
 */

@MultipartConfig
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
 private final static Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getCanonicalName());

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Connection con;
    Statement s; 
    final String path = "D:/6th sem/MP/OnlineExamination/web/app_data/questionbanks";
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);
      String branch = request.getParameter("branch");
      String sem = request.getParameter("semester");
      String course = request.getParameter("course");
      String name = request.getParameter("name");


    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
 try {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:online_testing");
           s=con.createStatement();
           String sql="insert into bank(branch,sem,course,bname) values('"+branch+"','"+sem+"','"+course+"','"+name+"')";
           s.executeUpdate(sql);
           String sql3="CREATE TABLE "+name+"(ID AUTOINCREMENT,question varchar(255),option1 varchar(255),option2 varchar(255),option3 varchar(255),option4 varchar(255),answer varchar(255)) ";
            s.executeUpdate(sql3);
            s.close();
            con.close();
             out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                + fileName));
        filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }


         request.getSession().setAttribute("msg", "Your Question bank has been uploaded");
        response.sendRedirect("fhome.jsp");



    }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            response.sendRedirect("fhome.jsp");
             request.getSession().setAttribute("msg", ex.getMessage().toString());

            Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,"exception occurred", ex);
        }       
            catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
          catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
         request.getSession().setAttribute("msg", "You did not specify a file to upload.");
        response.sendRedirect("fhome.jsp");


        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}", 
                new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
    } 
 finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (filecontent != null) {
            filecontent.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

    }

  private String getFileName(final Part part) {
    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: 1) Use `preparedStatement` if you deal with user input 2)Why in hell are you creating a new table at each user request?

Comment: because a new test is going to be prepared in this servlet.I will populate this table in the code that follows.

Comment: You exception has some descripition or caused by? If has, please post.

Comment: Seriously, you should use PreparedStatement. This is a classic security hole.

Comment: My log is empty...I am not able to see the reason too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you never call the `processRequest` method in your other methods. The `processRequest` method is not part of the Servlet API so you need to call it yourself.

Comment: Just shocked to see this.I have made numerous servlets till now in netbeans and it automatically calls process request in get and post method.This is the first servlet in my project without a call.
Thankyou for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a very bad idea, because the method is not documented to accept a `null` here in Java 6:

```
Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Replace it with something like

```
Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception occurred", ex);
```

and then check your log output - it should be logged.

Comment: Nope.still the same problem.It is not being logged

Comment: so did you check your logging configuration? can you log anything?

Comment: I have a similar servlet which can log a sql exception successfully.I had checked on it.I dont know what is the problem with this servlet.May be I should put my whole servlet code.Just have a look.I am editing question with full servlet code.Thanks

Comment: if nothing is logged or shown you cannot be sure it is an sqlexception at all.

Comment: When i am removing primary key constraint the code works fine